# React : Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

When I click the certain button to redirect to the page, the page did not show the content.

When I checked View => Developer => Developer Tools => console, it shows errors text below:

Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function
at ShoppingCart.js:6:1

at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:15846:1)

at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:16219:1)

at useMemo (react.development.js:1532:1)

at ShoppingCart (ShoppingCart.js:6:1)

at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)

at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)

at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)

at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)

at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)

The above error occurred in the  component:

```
at ShoppingCart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1063:68)
at div
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20449:23
at div
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23024:23
at div
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20648:23
at Menu (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2709:76)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:184334:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:184536:29)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:183969:30)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:183590:35)
at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1962:5)
at App
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

[Errors messages in Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRvzG.jpg)

[Error message in Developer Tools 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9O8f.jpg)

[rror message in Developer Tools 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugznq.png)

```
import { IoCloseOutline } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { fetchPlace } from '../apis';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import MenuList from '../components/MenuList';
import ShoppingCart from '../components/ShoppingCart';

const OrderButton = styled(Button)`
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
`;

const Menu = () => {
    const [place, setPlace] = useState({});
    const [shoppingCart, setShoppingCart] = useState({});
    const [showShoppingCart, setShowShoppingCart] = useState(false);

    const params = useParams();

    const onFetchPlace = async () => {
        const json = await fetchPlace(params.id);
        console.log(json);
        if (json) {
            setPlace(json);
        }
    };

    const onAddItemtoShoppingCart = (item) => {
        setShoppingCart({
            ...shoppingCart,
            [item.id]: {
                ...item,
                quantity: (shoppingCart[item.id]?.quantity || 0) + 1,
            }
        });
    }

    const onRemoveItemToShoppingCart = (item) => {
        if (totalQuantity === 1) {
            setShowShoppingCart(false);
        }

        setShoppingCart({
            ...shoppingCart,
            [item.id]: {
                ...item,
                quantity: (shoppingCart[item.id]?.quantity || 0) - 1,
            }
        });
    }

    const totalQuantity= useMemo(
        () => Object.keys(shoppingCart)
                .map((i) => shoppingCart[i].quantity)
                .reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0),
            [shoppingCart] 
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        onFetchPlace();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Container className="mt-5 mb-5">
            <Row className="justify-content-center">
                <Col lg={8}>
                    {showShoppingCart ? (
                        <ShoppingCart 
                            items={Object.keys(shoppingCart)
                                .map((key) => shoppingCart[key])
                                .filter((item) => item.quantity > 0)
                            }
                            onAdd={onAddItemtoShoppingCart}
                            onRemove={onRemoveItemToShoppingCart}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <MenuList 
                            place={place} 
                            shoppingCart={shoppingCart} 
                            onOrder={onAddItemtoShoppingCart} 
                        />
                    )}
                    
                </Col>
            </Row>

            {totalQuantity ? (
                <OrderButton variant="standard" onClick={() => setShowShoppingCart(!showShoppingCart)}>
                    {showShoppingCart ? <IoCloseOutline size={25} /> : totalQuantity}
                </OrderButton>
            ) : null}
        </Container>
    )
};

export default Menu;
```

Shopping Cart Code(Where the errors happened)

```
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import OperationButton from './OperationButton';

const ShoppingCart = ( items, onAdd, onRemove ) => {
    const totalPrice = useMemo(
        () => items.map((i) => i.quantity * i.price).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0),
        [items]
    );

    return (
        <>
            <h3 className="text-center mb-4">
                <b>Your Order</b>
            </h3>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    {items.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="d-flex mb-4 align-items-center">
                            <div className="flex-grow-1">
                                <p className="mb-0">
                                    <b>{item.name}</b>
                                </p>
                                <span>${item.price}</span>
                            </div>

                            <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <OperationButton
                                    variant="lightgray"
                                    size="sm"
                                    onClick={() => onRemove(item)}

                                >    
                                    -
                                </OperationButton>
                                <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                                <OperationButton
                                    variant="lightgray"
                                    size="sm"
                                    onClick={() => onAdd(item)}
                                    
                                >    
                                    +
                                </OperationButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}

                    <hr/>
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <h5><b>Total</b></h5>
                        <h5><b>{totalPrice}</b></h5>
                    </div>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </>
    );
};

export default ShoppingCart;
```

My package.json

```
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "qrcode.react": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.7",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the page
[This is the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QudMy.jpg)

In this page, after I click the "Add to shopping cart" button, one order button will be appeared at the right bottom of the page. After that, when I click the order button it will direct to a page and supposed it will shows like that.

[After click order button(Not mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRmvw.jpg)

However, for mine, it shows nothing.
[My page after click order button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMCsY.png)

Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const ShoppingCart = ( items, onAdd, onRemove ) => {` is not how you access the prop values. The component has one argument (props) not three arguments.

So you have just named props `items` which is an object, objects don't have `map` on them like arrays. Next time add a console log in to see what `items` is.

What you meant to do is [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props object:

```
const ShoppingCart = ({ items, onAdd, onRemove }) => {
```

Comment: It worked! I am complete beginner. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShoppingCart` component declaration is not right. Function components receive one argument only, the `props` object.

You can destruct the `prop` argument like this:

```js
const ShoppingCart = ({ items, onAdd, onRemove }) => {
//...
```

Comment: It worked! I am complete beginner. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

sorry, haven't read the full question. but you should always check if the array has length or not (which means it has some value or not).

```
items?.length && items.map()
```

**items?.length** will make sure if the array exists and has some length.

also you can use something like:

```
items?.length ? items.map() : 'no data found'
```